# How can i detect Formalin in food easily

Tags: biochemistry, home-experiment, food-chemistry

I am trying to detect formalin in different types of food. Formalin $(\ce{CH2(OH)2})$is an aqueous solution of formaldehyde, which is $\ce{CH2O}$ or $\ce{H2CO}$. I used many chemicals to do this, but every time I fail. Please help me to do this. I got some results in my test by using NFPA 704 and ChEMBL, but that is not enough to save all. I would like to make a simple and easy food formalin detector that can save all the people. Please help me or give me some direction.

Comment: Perhaps you are unable to detect formalin because it is not there. Formalin/formaldehyde has a very powerful and distinct smell that is [extremely unpleasant](http://www.idph.state.il.us/envhealth/factsheets/formaldehyde.htm). It can be detected at fairly low concentrations by your nose, which is perhaps the best sensor available for formaldehyde.

Comment: Also, what you you mean by "test by using NFPA 704, ChEMBL"? NFPA 704 is the code for the NFPA standard that gives us the [fire diamond](http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/document-information-pages?mode=code&code=704). ChEMBL is a database of properties of drug-like molecules for bioinformatics purposes.

Comment: **[This](http://formaldehydetests.com/)** might help you

Comment: Thanks to all... I am new in stackexchange. And I like Chemistry. I want to help everyone with my knowledge. If you know the formula or you have any article that I can get some idea please give me. We will very appreciate to you.

Comment: @Freddy - Would you be willing to expand/explain/summarize your link as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Simple commercially available tests contain **formaldehyde dehydrogenase.** This enzyme selectively catalyzes the chemical reaction of formaldehyde:

$$\ce{CH2O + NAD+ + H2O -> HCOO- + NADH + H+}$$

The enzymatic reaction is typically indicated by reduction of a tetrazolium salt to a coloured formazan dye.